# temporary image file in ruby

Tags: file, temp

hi i would like to know how I can create a temporary file image (png) in ruby, because tempfile only gets you a random file name but it doesn't have an extension file.

Answer (score 7):

[check the documentation!](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/classes/Tempfile.html#M004095)

```
  # Use the Array form to enforce an extension in the filename:
  file = Tempfile.new(['hello', '.jpg'])
  file.path  # => something like: "/tmp/foo2843-8392-92849382--0.jpg"
```